# Spring Integration WS inbound gateway Remove Soap empty header

Tags: spring, soap, spring-integration

My project using Spring integration ws-inbound-gateway.

```
<int-ws:inbound-gateway id="shop-inbound-gateway"           
            error-channel="shopCoreErrorChannel" 
            request-channel="shopRequestChannel" 
            reply-channel="shopResponseChannel" />
```

Response:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-     ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
           <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
           <SOAP-ENV:Body>
           <shop:RailShopAPIResponse>
            ......
            ......
           </shop:RailShopAPIResponse>
           </SOAP-ENV:Body>
        </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Even though I didn't map any `mapped-reply-headers`/`mapped-request-headers` but the response will always have the empty soap header.

- Why is this soap empty header is coming?
- Is it a default behavior?
- If so then how to remove the empty soap header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider to add some custom `EndpointInterceptor` to your `EndpointMapping` and implement clean up logic in the `handleResponse`:

```
/**
 * Processes the outgoing response message. Called after {@link EndpointAdapter} actually invoked the endpoint. Can
 * manipulate the response, if any, by adding new headers, etc.
```

Comment: Thank you @Artem bilan for your quick response. I will try your suggestion.